# Python pandas, how to transform a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe d1:

import pandas as pd

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({('sw1', '2020-01-01 00:00:00'): {'A1': 5.496714153011234,
  'B1': 4.536582307187538,
  'C1': 6.465648768921554},
 ('sw1', '2020-01-01 00:15:00'): {'A1': 5.417291254384371,
  'B1': 5.089825801985299,
  'C1': 5.32977925506902},
 ('sw2', '2020-01-01 00:00:00'): {'A1': 5.593791702359273,
  'B1': 3.1212115651371235,
  'C1': 4.546877553622513},
 ('sw2', '2020-01-01 00:15:00'): {'A1': 6.385936244917259,
  'B1': 4.66918047921994,
  'C1': 5.303265379619803},
 ('clust', ''): {'A1': 1, 'B1': 2, 'C1': 3}})
df1.columns.names = ['None', 'dtime']
df1.index.names = ['dev']
df1

>>> df1
None                  sw1                                     sw2                     clust
dtime 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-01-01 00:15:00 2020-01-01 00:00:00 2020-01-01 00:15:00
dev
A1               5.496714            5.417291            5.593792            6.385936     1
B1               4.536582            5.089826            3.121212            4.669180     2
C1               6.465649            5.329779            4.546878            5.303265     3
```

I would like to transform it to this format:

```
>>> df2
cust                        1                   2                   3
dev                        A1                  B1                  C1
sw                        sw1       sw2       sw1       sw2       sw1       sw2
dtime
2020-01-01 00:00:00  5.496714  5.593792  4.536582  3.121212  6.465649  4.546878
2020-01-01 00:15:00  5.417291  6.385936  5.089826  4.669180  5.329779  5.303265
```

How to do that?

(I am adding this text because stackoverflow gave to me the following error: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.", so I need to put some extra text in the post. Please Ignore.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `MultiIndex` column `clust` to index with select by tuple and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True` for avoid lost `dev` values, then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), last change order in `MultiIndex` and sorting by [`DataFrame.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = (df1.set_index(('clust',''), append=True)
         .rename_axis(index=('dev','clust'), columns=('sw','dtime'))
         .stack()
         .unstack([0,1])
         .reorder_levels((2,1,0), axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1)
        )
print (df)
clust                       1                   2                   3  \
dev                        A1                  B1                  C1   
sw                        sw1       sw2       sw1       sw2       sw1   
dtime                                                                   
2020-01-01 00:00:00  5.496714  5.593792  4.536582  3.121212  6.465649   
2020-01-01 00:15:00  5.417291  6.385936  5.089826  4.669180  5.329779   

clust                          
dev                            
sw                        sw2  
dtime                          
2020-01-01 00:00:00  4.546878  
2020-01-01 00:15:00  5.303265
```

Similar solution with reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and transpose:

```
df = (df1.set_index(('clust',''), append=True)
         .rename_axis(index=('dev','clust'), columns=('sw','dtime'))
         .stack(0)
         .T
         .reorder_levels((1,0,2), axis=1)
        )
print (df)
clust                       1                   2                   3  \
dev                        A1                  B1                  C1   
sw                        sw1       sw2       sw1       sw2       sw1   
dtime                                                                   
2020-01-01 00:00:00  5.496714  5.593792  4.536582  3.121212  6.465649   
2020-01-01 00:15:00  5.417291  6.385936  5.089826  4.669180  5.329779   

clust                          
dev                            
sw                        sw2  
dtime                          
2020-01-01 00:00:00  4.546878  
2020-01-01 00:15:00  5.303265
```

Comment: the second one is clean nice one

Comment: Both solutions are excellent. I don't understand why you needed tuple with empty string as a second parameter. 

Your first solution I have changed to:
(df1.set_index(('clust'), append=True)
         .rename_axis(columns=('sw','dtime'))
         .stack()
         .unstack([0,1])
         .reorder_levels((2,1,0), axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1)
        )

and second to:

(df1.set_index('clust', append=True)
         .rename_axis(columns=('sw','dtime'))
         .stack(0)
         .T
         .reorder_levels((1,0,2), axis=1)
        )

Thank you very very much jezrael.

Comment: @user3225309 - Reason is if check `print (df.columns.tolist())` all columns are in `MultiIndex`

Comment: Now I see why. Thanks for an explanation.